# Getting statistics for my hikes (duration, length, elevation, etc.), preferably for free

Tags: gps, tracking

I like hiking, and I use the Locus Map Pro app on Android to record my tracks. I would like to get statistics for my track, such as for example:

- the average length of my tracks
- maximum duration, minimum duration
- average elevation going up
- etc.

Of course they may be other summary statistics which make sense for hiking: these are just examples. I'd like not to do that by hand, by downloading each track, having to understand the file format and implementing the summary statistic computations myself. Is there a solution? I'd prefer free solutions if possible, but I can also accept paid ones, as long as they are reasonably cheap.

PS I included the app name because I didn't see anything [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) against it, but I can delete it if you think that would be more appropriate.

Comment: @whrrgarbl According to the meta, this question is on topic https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/questions-and-or-recommendations-about-software-electronic-devices-related-to

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh thanks, I did not find that question earlier.. apparently the tag "topics" is used sometimes instead of "on-topic" on meta. I had already posted a question here: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/lets-fill-out-the-on-topic-page which I will update with this new information. I don't agree that the answer there indicates support of software *recommendations*, only outdoor-software *questions*.

Comment: @DeltaIV Not really, it's the difference between "How do I use X to do Y?" and "What can I use to do Y?" I read your question as "what app or software can I use to get statistics" and not "how do I get statistics in this particular app", my apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: @whrrgarbl hmm, if you substitute "app or software" with "_website_ or app or software" you mostly got my question right. Ok, you convinced me, I flagged the question for migration. I still suspect that somehow the answer would have been of interest to people here, but I cannot make a valid argument for my suspicion, so migration it is! Why don't you custom flag it too? More flags may result in the question being migrated sooner